# How do I deal with non-ASCII characters in IO operations?

Tags: haskell, encoding, filenames

As the title says, I'm having a problem dealing with characters outside of ASCII (like 'á','ã', etc) in IO operations. Look at the example (Unix environment):

```
import System.Cmd
system "ls aaaá"
```

Which returns the ls command code error:

```
(...)ls: can't access "aaa�" : no such file or directory(...)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like `system` just truncates character codes above 255. I guess you need to convert the string to your locale's encoding (probably UTF8) first.

Comment: Last time I checked, Linux uses UTF-8 for file names. I don't think the `system` function does this conversion automatically.

Comment: I have just checked on my system (Ubuntu, GHC 7.2.1) and it just works without any conversion. (My previous comment was a pure guess, I was away from my computer). Perhaps you're using a non-UTF locale.

Comment: Possibly related to [GHC #4006](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4006) (fixed in 7.2.1).

Comment: @ChrisWong: filenames in Linux have no fixed encoding, but programs will typically write them in the encoding given by the locale. So with `LC_ALL=en.US.UTF-8`, you will get UTF-8 encoded filenames. You're correct that UTF-8 is the default encoding for modern distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on hammar's comment, I installed GHC v7.2.2 (my old version was v6.9.9), and the bug was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your system locale
2. Check the encoding of your Haskell sources

If both are UTF8 it should work.

Comment: I check and reconfigure the localeconf package to use a UTF8 codification. Now, how do I check the encoding of my Haskell sources? I tried with `System.IO -> hSetEncoding stdin UTF8` but it did not work :s

Comment: Try `file foo.hs` (in a shell) and see what encoding it reports.

Comment: (But I suspect the GHC bug n.m. and hammar mentioned in the comments of your question is the real answer.)